# Art Gallery Problem for the Castro's $24$-sided room

Tags: computational-geometry

> **Art Gallery Theorem**. *If the walls of an art gallery are made up of* $n$  *straight line segments, then the entire gallery can always be supervised by* $\lfloor{\frac{n}{3}}\rfloor$  *watchmen placed in corners.*

How can I find $\lfloor{\frac{24}{3}}\rfloor=8$ points (corners) in the Castro's room according the [Art Gallery Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArtGalleryTheorem.html)?

```
Castro24 = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {3, -1}, 
{3, -1}, {2, -1}, {2, -2}, {1, -1}, {0, -1}, {0,-2}, {-1, -1}, {-2, -2},{-2, -1},
{-3, -1}, {-4, 0}, {-3, 0}, {-3, 1},  {-2, 2}, {-2, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}};

Graphics[{Blue, Line[First[#]]} & /@ {{Castro24}}]
```

[image]

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas

Comment: Creating a graph which shows which corners can supervise which other corners is likely helpful.

Comment: Couldn't you do it in three? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf7AM.png

Comment: I think `RegionWithin` is buggy. I get `True` for `RegionWithin[Polygon[Castro24], Line[{Castro24[[{19, 21}]]}]]` but look at `Graphics[{LightBlue, Polygon[Castro24], Red, 
  Line[{Castro24[[{19, 21}]]}]}]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: related: [Agent Navigates Maze](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/872077)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A constructive application of [Fisk's short proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem#Fisk.27s_short_proof): triangulate the polygon, 3-colour its vertices, and pick the smallest colour set.

```
triangulation = DiscretizeRegion[Polygon[Castro24], MaxCellMeasure -> ∞];
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
vertices = MeshCoordinates[triangulation] /. {x_, y_} :> {{x, y}};
edges = MeshCells[triangulation, 1] /. Line[{a_, b_}] :> {{a, b}};
graph = Combinatorica`Graph[edges, vertices];
colouring = MinimumVertexColoring[graph, 3];
colour = 6 - Total@Commonest[colouring, 2]; (* least common of {1, 2, 3} *)
ShowGraph[Highlight[graph, Flatten@Position[colouring, colour]]]
```

[image]